# Mixing Masonry and jQuery.Lazy();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an image site, where i am loading af lot of images in a Masonry grid. When using jQuery.Lazy();, my images begin to overlap.

html:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
            <img  class="lazy" src="path/to/img">
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
               var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
              // init Masonry after all images have loaded
              $grid.masonry({
                // options...
              });
            }); 

        });

        $(function() {
            $('.lazy').Lazy();
        });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-item {
float: left;
width: 25%;
padding: 5px;
}
```

i hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to with Masonry.js, it is your implementation of CSS.

You are floating .grid-item and setting a width of 25% to this class. However, the images within are still using their native dimensions.

Try this:

```
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
```